# c++ - segmentation fault after reading object in file re-openned

Tags: c++, file

I got an issue that I can't solve, when I'm trying to read a file that was previously closed but that I re-open I got a segmentation fault as soon as i use the object (`newT`) I got a segmentation fault but I have no problem for reading `n` which is the number of objet to read. What's wierd is that if it's a new file that i'm reading I have no problem, so what am I doing wrong ?

Here is the code:

Creating file function:

```
char* CreerHoraire(fstream& fichier, char* nomFichier)
{
    if(fichier.is_open())
        cout<<"Vous devez fermer le fichier en cours avant d'en créer un autre"<<endl;
    else
    {
        saisieNomFichier(nomFichier);
        fichier.open(nomFichier, fstream::in | fstream::out | fstream::binary);
        if(fichier)
            cout<<"Le fichier "<<nomFichier<<" a bien été ouvert"<<endl;
        else//if file doesn't exist I create it (no problem here)
        {
            fichier.open(nomFichier, fstream::in | fstream::out | fstream::binary |fstream::trunc);

            if(fichier)
                cout<<"Le fichier "<<nomFichier<<" a bien été créé"<<endl;
            else
                cout<<"Le fichier "<<nomFichier<<" a rencontré un problème à sa création !"<<endl;
        }
    }

    return nomFichier;
}
```

Reading function

```
template<typename T>
void ListeTriee<T>::load(ifstream& fichier)
{
    if(fichier.fail()) 
        throw InvalidException("Erreur ouverture fichier");
    else
    {
        int n;
        T newT;

        fichier.read ((char *)&n, sizeof(int));

        while(n)
        {
            fichier.read ((char*) &newT, sizeof(newT));
                    newT.Affiche();//seg fault

            this->insere(newT);//quand on utilise newT après lu
            n--;
        }
    }

    if(!fichier) throw InvalidException("Erreur lecture fichier");
}
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Please show a minimal, working example, and what line of code is throwing the exception.

Comment: How do you know `fichier.read ((char *)&n, sizeof(int));` was successful?

Comment: Actually  I don't but because the first read worked I assumed it does, but you right it's a possibility so if it doesn't work what could cause this, do I open the file right ? (one thing for sure the read() doesn't directly ccause the seg fault)

Comment: You need to ensure that `T` is [trivially copyable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_trivially_copyable) or implement proper serialisation.

Comment: You expecting to be able to deserialize an arbitrary object from a chunk of bytes read from a file without having actually written any code to do that.

Answer (score 2):

You should have a real serialization / deserialization of your objects to the file. "Constructing" objects (with functions in them) by copying bytes from a file is invalid.

It can work for POD (data-only) objects without any references to memory elsewhere (no pointers), but for other content, writing / reading raw bytes doesn't work - the memory adresses, for instance, will be all wrong when you reload the object.

Comment: Ok thanks. But apparently I need to use boost Library for serialization, and I can only use standrad Library for this project :s